# ORACLE - How to check two dates between from-date and to-date?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, sql-date-functions

I have a table with information about periods of sells and now I need to know if some row is overlap each other. Eg: If there are a period with '01/12/2016' to '31/01/2017' I want to know if some row is overlapped for example '15/12/2016' to '28/02/2017'. Do you have any idea?

```
 NUMBER(5)        DATE                 DATE
 Period No.       from date            to-date
-----------------------------------------
9891              01/06/2016         31/07/2016   
9892              01/08/2016         30/09/2016   
9893              01/09/2016         31/10/2016 -- This row is overlapped
9894              01/11/2016         31/12/2016
9895              15/12/2016         28/02/2017 -- This row is overlapped
9896              01/03/2017         31/05/2017
```

I know the logic for check one date between two dates (WHERE v_date_1 BETWEEN
v_date_2 AND v_date_3) but I don't know how to check two dates between two dates!. Thanks.

Comment: See [my blog post](http://tonyandrews.blogspot.co.uk/search/label/overlap)

Comment: Are FROM_DATE and TO_DATE of `date` data type? (They should be!)

Comment: @TonyAndrews Please check the link you just posted. It is not working for me.

Comment: @mathguy it is now!

Comment: Date! sorry, my error

Comment: I assume `9895` appearing twice in the first column is a typo, and the column is in fact unique? (meaning no duplicates?)

Comment: @mathguy has raised an important question, if this is unique then the process is simple, can you advise please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what format you desire for the output. Here is one way to do this.

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy';
with
     test_data ( period_no, from_dt, to_dt ) as (
     select 9891, to_date('01/06/2016'), to_date('31/07/2016') from dual union all
     select 9892, to_date('01/08/2016'), to_date('30/09/2016') from dual union all   
     select 9893, to_date('01/09/2016'), to_date('31/10/2016') from dual union all
     select 9894, to_date('01/11/2016'), to_date('31/12/2016') from dual union all
     select 9895, to_date('15/12/2016'), to_date('28/02/2017') from dual union all
     select 9896, to_date('01/03/2017'), to_date('31/05/2017') from dual
     )
-- End of simulated table (for testing purposes only, not part of the solution).
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE.
select a.period_no as period_a, a.from_dt as from_dt_a, a.to_dt as to_dt_a,
       b.period_no as period_b, b.from_dt as from_dt_b, b.to_dt as to_dt_b
from   test_data a
       join
       test_data b
         on  a.period_no <  b.period_no 
         and a.to_dt     >= b.from_dt
         and b.to_dt     >= a.from_dt
;

  PERIOD_A FROM_DT_A  TO_DT_A      PERIOD_B FROM_DT_B  TO_DT_B  
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      9892 01/08/2016 30/09/2016       9893 01/09/2016 31/10/2016
      9894 01/11/2016 31/12/2016       9895 15/12/2016 28/02/2017
```

We join the table to itself since we want to compare different rows (in the same table instead of in different tables, but the concept is the same - for such comparisons, you join the tables, even if it is two copies of the same table). That's called a "self join".

Then: there are two ways in which time intervals may NOT overlap: the first one ends before the second one begins, or the second one ends before the first one begins. Now NEGATE this condition (remember that the negation of "or" is "and") and you get the two extra conditions in the JOIN clause.

Comment: Thanks Mathguy for your help and explication. It works fine and now I understand how use it. Thanks again :)